# Multiply All Values By Single Value In Arrays Of GET Updated Data Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, get

I have a JSON object that stores data from an API GET request. Each object in the object has two arrays. I need to multiply the second array (the y value). The data is stored like so:

```
  var apiData = {
  'id1': {
    x: [],
    y: []
  },
  'id2': {
    x: [],
    y: []
  },
  'id3': {
    x: [],
    y: []
  },
```

Etc. There are 50 arrays that need each of their values multiplied.

I understand I need to do something like this:

```
var multiplyFunction = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < apiData.length; i++);
  [do something]
}
```

How exactly can I multiply all the elements in the y arrays by a single number (like 1,000), though? I've looked at a few other topics and it wasn't clear. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I've found a solution by multiplying the values as they are being pushed to the array from the API data. Like so:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    apiDataObject[id].x.push(data[i][0]);
    /* Multiply each value by 1,000 to convert units. */
    apiDataObject[id].y.push(data[i][1] * 1000);
  }
```

This is also better for browser compatibility.

Comment: so you need to multiple `id2.y` elements by `x`?

Comment: I need to multiply all the numbers in the y arrays by a single number, like 1,000.

Comment: you have 3 `y` arrays

Comment: More than that! 50, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by multiplying the values as they are being pushed to the array from the API data. Like so:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        apiDataObject[id].x.push(data[i][0]);
        /* Multiply each value by 1,000 to convert units. */
        apiDataObject[id].y.push(data[i][1] * 1000);
      }
```

This is also better for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Solution.

```
var multiplier = 1000;
Object.keys(apiData).forEach(key => {
  apiData[key].y = apiData[key].y.map(item => item * multiplier);
});
```

Comment: Hate to dump this code on you, but for whatever reason, the functions seems to creating much larger values than intended. For instance, California (118,000 x 1000) should be 118M not 1.18624 x 10^43.

Here’s the link to the Github index.html: https://github.com/dieterholger/21st-Century-US-Jet-Fuel-Explorer/blob/master/index.html

Comment: For each state it is firing individual request and each time its multiplying the main value by the multiplier thus causing the value to become very large. You would need to add check to the main request to only update the value for the particular state.

Comment: Yes. I've found a workaround/solution by just multiplying the values from the get request as they are pushed. I believe this is faster and better for compatibility as well. Probably should've been more clear that I was pushing the data into the arrays in an earlier function. I posted my solution here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Object.keys(apiData).forEach(key => {
  // 1000 - it's a number what you need
  apiData[key].y = apiData[key].y.map(x => x * 1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

apiData is not array, this is object.

https://jsbin.com/sitonogoso/edit?html,js,console

```
// es5
var multiplyFunction = function() {
  var y = 1;


  for (key in apiData) {
    var data = apiData[key];

    // array = y;
    var array = data.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      // y = y * array[i];
    }
  }

  return y;
}

console.log(multiplyFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to support IE, then your best bet would be to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), followed by an [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let apiData = {
  'id1': {
    x: [],
    y: [5, 8]
  },
  'id2': {
    x: [],
    y: [9, 6]
  },
  'id3': {
    x: [],
    y: [50, 31]
  }
};

let multiplier = 100;

Object.values(apiData).forEach(item => {
  item.y = item.y.map(number => number * multiplier);
});

console.log(apiData);
```

Comment: Hate to dump this code on you, but for whatever reason, the functions seems to creating much larger values than intended when using a 1,000 multiplier. For instance, California (118,000 x 1000) should be 118M not 1.18624 x 10^43.

Here’s the link to the Github index.html: https://github.com/dieterholger/21st-Century-US-Jet-Fuel-Explorer/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @dataondata -- I didn't get you. Are you saying that instead of 118000000, this gives you `1.18624 * 10^43`?

Comment: Yes. To be exact, it gives 1.1862399999999994e+143. It should be just be 118,000,000. Wisconsin also becomes 1.769T instead of what it should be, 1,769,000. This is for all the first values in the arrays.

Comment: @dataondata -- can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: I was able to take out the relevant parts. But the API get request only runs and fills in the data onload. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rainbowunicorn161/kubnpgos/2/